# web optimization not rendering bundle

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web-optimization

I have the following bundle configuration for my javascript.

```
`BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Includes/Shop/js/bundles/abc").Include(
                "~/Includes/Shop/js/vendor/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Includes/Shop/js/vendor/jquery-ajaxq.js",
                "~/Includes/Shop/js/vendor/knockout-{version}.js",
                "~/Includes/Shop/js/vendor/lodash-{version}.js"
                ));`
```

The issue is when I call it in my partial view, it's just outputting the "Includes/Shop/js/bundles/abc" as the script source. The optimization part is turned off.

Should point out I am using this with sitecore cms.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NAMESPACE.UI.BundleConfig), "Start")]
```

What would cause the bundle not to output these files, I know they exist on the file system.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what you want to achieve? Single "Includes/Shop/js/bundles/abc" script which included code from all 4 javascripts added in "Include(..." section? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well true, but I have BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; which should just render file by file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turns out to have been the version of web grease, 1.5.2 didn't work, but 1.6 did.

Answer (score 0):

i had that issue once i've just re run the nuget-package installation commands of [webgrace](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebGrease/) and [optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/) then it worked out